# Identify this movie about ghouls in a desert and a car stonehenge

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie around 2006, on Foxtel(movie channel) in Australia.

It was set in a desert town where something scary was going on.

I remember one or two characters descending into a manhole or tunnel in the streets of the town. After a while they run into some sort of ghouls or vampire like creatures and they promptly run away.

They escape by climbing up the ladder out of the manhole/tunnel and the creatures do not follow them for some reason. I am unsure if it was because of light sensitivity or an action the characters took.

The only other scene I can remember is them reaching a sort of car stonehenge in the desert and I believe the movie ended shortly after this event.

The movie was in colour and I believe it was a recent release at the time.

Comment: Sounds like they ended up in [car henge](http://carhenge.com).

Comment: this reminds me about one of the scene in maze runner scorch trial.